# How to change the value of related model

Tags: python, django

This line of code is iterating through the related queryset:

```
order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
for order_item in order.items.all():
  order_item.item.quantity += 1
```

Its changing the value of `quantity` (I can see that using (`print(order_item.item.quantity)`), but it doesn't save in the database. I have tried `order.save()`, but the value stays the same (before `+=1`).
What I have to do to save new value to the database?

Comment: Don't you need to explicitly persist it to db?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `save()` to store it:

```
order = Order.objects.get(user=self.request.user, ordered=False)
for order_item in order.items.all():
  item = order_item.item
  item.quantity += 1
  item.save()
```

Or, do it in one query using [**`update()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once):

```
from django.db.models import F

Item.objects.filter(orderitem__order__user=self.request.user, orderitem__order__ordered=False).update(quantity=F('quantity')+1)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to pass all the values from the for loop? Let say that `item.quantity` returns 3 values in the for loop, but when I am calling `item.quantity` outside the loop I get just the last value. How I can get all the values?

Comment: you can use .values_list(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: Ok it returns a queryset, but I cant use it for If statement. I wanted to create an if statement that checks if any value in `item.quantity` is less than 1. I have created the values_list `v = order.items.values_list('item__quantity', flat=True)` and then tried to run `if v >= 1` , but it says that its not supported. Any ideas?

Comment: obviously, it is returning a list. you need to run like this. `if len(v) >= 1:`

Comment: but len(v) is returning the length of the list and I am talking about the values inside. For example v is returning: `<QuerySet [5, 2]>` and I want to check if every single item in that query matches `>=1`

Comment: in that case you need to loop though it. If you want to return which items are bigger than 0, then use filter like this: `print(list(filter(lambda x: x>=1, v)))`

Comment: I wanna run a function based on the values in that queryset. If all the items inside meet `>=1`, then the function would run if not then it goes to `else`

Comment: then use `if all(map(lambda x: x>=1, v)):